# Calculate velocity of a bullet ricocheting on a circle

Tags: java, physics

I made a picture to demostrate what I need,basecaly I have a bullet with velocity and I want it to bounce with the correct angle after it hits a circle

**Solved**(look the accepted answer for explain):

```
Vector.vector.set(bullet.vel);    //->v
Vector.vector2.setDirection(pos, bullet.pos);     //->n normal from center of circle to bullet
float dot=Vector.vector.dot(Vector.vector2);    //->dot product
Vector.vector2.mul(dot).mul(2);
Vector.vector.sub(Vector.vector2);  
Vector.vector.y=-Vector.vector.y;  //->for some reason i had to invert the y
Vector.vector.normalize();
bullet.vel.set(Vector.vector);
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need direction or velocity? If direction that is elementary school [stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(physics))... and you are already doing it in almost any shading model.

Comment: @wondra  just the direction.Well many years have passed since  elementary :)

Comment: Find the slope of the circle at the point of intersection (the derivative). Use that slope/line as the line of reflection for the incoming bullet.

Comment: Some explain for the downvotes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for reflecting an incoming vector `v` across a unit normal `n` into an outgoing vector `v'` is

```
v' = v - 2*dot(v,n)*n
```

You can determine the normal `n` from normalizing the difference of the collision point and the center of the circle.

See the question on [How to get a reflection vector?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13261/how-to-get-a-reflection-vector) over on Math.SX for more elaborate derivations.